# Is it legal to create pointer to object for a static class?

Tags: c++

Is it legal to create pointer to object for a static class in C++?
And sorry if my question is silly.

Example:

```
static class_name *obj = NULL;
```

what does the above code does?

Comment: There is no static class. `obj` is a static variable of pointer to `class_name` type.

Comment: Its confusing when i think in this way, when class_name is a type like int . Then why they are using different class_name , instead of using some common type? like int,char etc ....Thanks @VTT

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is no such thing like a static class as you might know it from C#. What the code does, is to declare and initialize a static member of some class or a static variable inside a function.

So the variable `obj` is static, not the class it points to.